# How do FPGA's implement sequential circuits?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, verilog

I know they implement combinational circuits using LUTs, but LUTs don't have feedback, so I don't see how they can be used for sequential circuits.

So how do FPGA's implement sequential circuits? (i.e. D-Flip Flops and Registers)

Comment: If you were to look at the [architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array#Architecture) for a Field Programmable Gate Array you'd find a logic block generally has a flip flop associated with it.  (And it's generally also possible to route feed back into a LUT externally).

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing (technical) to stop you routing the output of a LUT back to the input to create storage.

But it's not a good idea as in most (all?) current FPGA families there is at least one flip-flop very closely coupled with each LUT.  In some families some of those FFs can be configured as latches instead.

Comment: Do FPGA devices generally specify that their LUTS are hazard-free for at least some combination of inputs? If not, I don't think feedback-based logic using LUTs alone would be "safe".

Comment: I seem to recall that (at least) Xilinx LUTs are hazard-free, but I agree, safety would be something for the user to ensure (in the same way as using discrete gates).  Much better to use the FFs provided!

Answer (score 0):

All FPGAs contain LUTs as well as configurable flip-flops/latches.  Even with just LUTs, the routing network has enough capability to route a LUT output back to an input to get feedback within one LUT or between several LUTs.  They also usually contain block RAM that can be configured with multiple ports of various widths or be used as a FIFO.  The LUTs can generally also be used as small RAMs (a LUT is basically just a read-only memory after it is written during the startup sequence, but adding a few more pins can make it read/write) or even shift registers.